# Node.js: How to install NPM

Tags: node.js, cygwin, npm

I have cygwin and node.exe (0.5.7) installed on my window XP.

When I `git clone npm(1.0.30), cd npm, then "make install"`, there are lots of node_modules cloning.

But it stopped when execute `"node cli.js install git+https://github.com/isaac/ronnjs.git"`.

The following is my **npm-debug.log**.

info it worked if it ends with ok

> verbose cli [ 'E:\node\node.exe',
>  verbose cli
>   'e:\github\npm\cli.js',
>  verbose cli 'cache',
>  verbose cli
>   'clean' ]
>  info using npm@1.0.30
>  info using node@v0.5.7
>   verbose config file C:\Documents and Settings\zhangchiqing.npmrc
>   verbose config file E:\etc\npmrc
>  ERR! prefix directory not
>   found
>  ERR! Error: ENOENT, �����ɹ����ɡ�
>  ERR! 'E:'
>  ERR!
>   Report this entire log at:
>  ERR!
>   http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
>  ERR! or email it to:
>  ERR!
>   npm-@googlegroups.com
>  ERR! 
>  ERR! System Windows_NT
>   5.1.2600
>  ERR! command "E:\node\node.exe" "e:\github\npm\cli.js" "cache" "clean"
>  ERR! cwd E:\github\npm
>  ERR! node -v v0.5.7
>   ERR! npm -v 1.0.30
>  verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Problems with npm should go on the github page. AFAIK, NPM isn't supported on 0.5.x, and especially not supported on Cygwin. Try something in the 0.4.x range. Also, have you tried Isaac's install script? It works wonders in Bash: `curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

Comment: Did you follow the step to create the link as described under installation? I do not see you mention that. "and link mongo_hacker.js to .mongorc.js in your home directory:"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works in Ubuntu. You have to use older version of node.

```
sudo apt-get install -y g++ libssl-dev apache2-utils curl git-core
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
git checkout v0.4.11
./configure
make
sudo make install
node -v
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
npm -v
```